# Should the "Which games use a neural network to influence gameplay?" question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing, specific-question, game-identification

Recently, the question, **[Which games use a neural network to influence game play?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399931/4797)** was [closed as an off-topic game identification question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/320632) and [left closed in the Reopen review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/320658).

Should it be reopened?

I don't think that it is an off-topic game identification question. It's not the "I remember this thing about a game, what game was it"? type of game identification question that we close as off-topic here. I believe the close reason was used incorrectly. It's more similar to other on-topic [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) questions on this site.

As for the question asking for a list or its topic broadness, I think a question should be closed for that reason *only* if it is asking for an unbounded or open-ended list, or a very large list of items, which is not the case for this specific question. According to [Arqade's site tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), one shouldn't ask about:

> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

I don't think the question fits that criteria. Several positively-received [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) questions actually have multiple games in the answers.

Related meta post about a similar list-type question where the community voted to reopen: [Why was my question about games in a compilation closed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6887/4797)

---

Also, I concur with @pppery's comment regarding moderator actions on a disputed question:

> Also note the question was closed by a moderator acting doubly (meaning it would have taken two community members without diamonds to close the question) despite having passed the close vote queue, and then left closed again by the same moderator acting doubly. This sort of question is not the right time for moderators to use their moderator powers. [...]

Comment: Also note the question was closed by a moderator acting doubly (meaning it would have taken two community members without diamonds to close the question) despite having passed the close vote queue, and then left closed again by the same moderator acting doubly. This sort of question is not the right time for moderators to use their moderator powers. (Disclosure: I was the first reopen voter)

Comment: @pppery sigh.... it's annoying how even if I got through the review queues, my mod powers still "work".  I still feel the question isn't suitable. Me and 3 other 20k+ reputation users seem to agree. All I'm going to say is reference my original comment on the question. It just doesn't quite fit the Q&A format and would need updating should new games be developed that use neural networks meaning. Questions and answers like that... just don't sit right for me for this site.

Comment: @TimmyJim Your original closure wasn't in the review queue, and was in fact after the community had left the question open in the review queue by 3 to 1.

Comment: @pppery I meant the reopen review. Pretty sure that was through the queue.

Comment: It might not be game identification but it pretty clearly falls into a [list of games that match a given criteria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1618/28182), which is one of the off topic criteria of game recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

My first problem is that if this can be closed as an identification question, so can any of the numerous "*What is the first game to...?*" under the [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) tag, proving that just because a question technically fits a closing reason doesn't mean that question should be closed.

This true-but-objection also applies to the arguments mentioned in the comments:

- > "Which game(s) satisfy " is game identification. It's also not good for the Q&A format because there is no way to give a single correct answer."
- > This is basically asking for a rolling list of games that meet a criteria.

If these are the only reasons we have for closing this particular question, we need to revise our [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) tag info (which would be fine by me :).

But like the "*What is the first game to ...?*" question type, this question asks for a ***finite list that can potentially be given in a single (and thus correct) answer*** (we could even start a community answer on this type of question by default so everyone is encouraged to pitch in).
The 'rolling' property of the list *can* be prevented; is not a limitation given by the OP (in that sense "this is basically asking for" is untrue); and is in any case not necessarily a reason to close a question.

Remember that a question should not be judged by its answers: I believe this applies to potential answers as well.

Comment: I do however get Timmy's frustration with it, but I can't really put my finger on why that is exactly.

Comment: "_What is the first game to_" has historically been accepted on the site, whether I agree with it or not (I think these particular questions are barely passable).  The post that this meta is about wants to know **all** the games that _do this_ or _have this trait_.  This would be a rolling continuous list that, in theory, never has an end if more games are released that meet the criteria that the post was about, meaning answers could become outdated and would need to be maintained.  That's my bigger issue with it.  That, and it doesn't quite fit the Q&A format that all SE sites are based on.

Comment: @TimmyJim Community user necro'd and I've just seen this. "What was the first game to" was actually off-topic for years (part of an older version of the Game ID close reason even!). It's definitely contentious: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28182